# How to compare two dates of dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: date, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have two files and want compare yours compilation dates for a future update.

Suppose that the new file have a date: 20/09/2019, and old file a date: 19/09/2019. How compare these two date on same format (dd/mm/yyyy)?

```
var
 UpDate, OldDate: string;
begin
  UpDate := '20/09/2019';
  OldDate := DateToStr(FileDateToDateTime(FileAge(IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'test.exe'))) // 19/09/2019

  if UpDate > OldDate then
  begin
    // Do something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Compare dates, not strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of manipulating strings, you can deal directly with `TDateTime` values by invoking [`DateUtils.CompareDate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DateUtils.CompareDate).

```
var  OldDate, UpDate : TDateTime;
begin
  OldDate := EncodeDate(2019, 9, 20);
  UpDate := FileDateToDateTime(FileAge(IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'test.exe'));
  if CompareDate(OldDate, UpDate) = LessThanValue  Then
  begin
    // Do something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: For whatever reason the result is actually a `TValueRelationship`, but effective result is the same. Linking to official [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.CompareDate) will reveal such details.

Comment: @Amessihel, **E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'DateTime'** on: `OldDate := Datetime.Create(2019, 9, 20);`

Comment: That create should be TDateTime.Create(...);

Comment: @PatHeuvel, **'TDateTime' does not contain a member named 'Create'**.

Comment: Note that using `FileDateToDateTime(FileAge(...))` is deprecated, use the overloaded version of `FileAge()` that outputs a `TDateTime` instead: `if FileAge(FileName, UpDate) then ...`

Comment: @BrowJr, oops - looking at the C++ Create! Sorry.